# How does performance of TCP and Unix Domain Sockets scale with number of processes and payload size?

Tags: sockets, tcp, scalability, unix-socket

Say I've a server on the same machine as some workers, each of which is talking to it. They could be talking over TCP or Unix Domain Sockets. How does the performance scale with number of workers and message size?

When I speak of performance, I'm looking for not only mean latencies, but also p90 and p99 latencies.

Comment: This is dependent on many factors, the only answer is to perform benchmarks of your application.

Answer (score 0):

As for TCP you can measure its performance youself ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650906/184968)). Do a few tests. 
Set the length of buffer to read or write and run [iperf](https://www.google.com/search?q=iperf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a) in server mode and also run a few iperf processes in client mode.  Then change the length of buffer to read or write.