# TCP/IP on localhost slow

Tags: performance, tcp, localhost

I have two C-Applications, both running on the same machine on windows XP. Based on the data in this thread: [Sockets On Same Machine For Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644851/sockets-on-same-machine-for-windows-and-linux) I should see very high speed on this connection.
But I can not transfer more than 500mbit/s. I use 127.0.0.1 as IP-Adress, and also the nodelay option. A single message has about 3.5mbyte and I have to send up to 30 of those message per second.
If there is no possibility I will have to zip those message somehow, but this will create a huge overhead of CPU-Load.
Any idea?

Comment: You're not saying anything about your CPU(s), your RAM and your data source.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the buffer you are sending can have a big impact on performance. For instance, if you use a small buffer you will be doing a lot of costly writes where only one is necessary.

I recommend you too make writes of 1492 bytes, that's about the size TCP usually handles. You can play around with other values to see if you get better performance.

Comment: I write the whole data within one write, so about 3.5MByte.

I'm implementing now a shared memory to handle these messages, so the problem will be solved.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say loading 3.5MB is a good practice. I don't really think the loading would be making a big overhead, nevertheless, you could give a smaller buffer a try, that way you don't have the initial loading overhead before start sending it. Even better if you do non blocking writes.